# Why is my android application skipping frames when Thread.sleep is called?

Tags: java, android, sleep

I'm writing an android application which needs to display some text for a a few thousandths of a second, then blank it again. What I have now is it displaying the text, then using Thread.sleep, then setting the text back to null. Instead, what happens is, when I press the button, the app hangs for the set amount of time, the text never appears, and the logcat says "Skipped xxx frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." What is going on, and is there a better way of doing things?

Comment: on which device you are testing it ?

Comment: ok well not sure about that device, but some devices doesnt support `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: @Lucifer - Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a runnable.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

//code to make text appear...

    mHandler.postDelayed(makeTextDisapear , 3000); // Replace 3000 with the number of milliseconds you want the text to display.

    private Runnable makeTextDisapear = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // code to make text dissapear

                }
            };
```

Comment: When I try this, it says "Illegal modifier for parameter mHandler; only final is permitted"

Comment: Yeah, it works when I do that, just checking if there was some reason you used private instead of final.

Comment: If you declare the variable at a higher scope you can use private.  You probably declared it inside of a method.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst other answers help solve your issue, your question was also why is this happening:

Calling either of the `Thread.sleep()` static methods puts the Thread which the method was invoked from into a paused state for (roughly) the amount of time that you specify (it isn't guaranteed to exactly match the specified time).

In Android, Ui operations have to be performed on the 'main' ui thread, as the Ui framework isn't designed to be thread safe. That is, when you set the text of a `TextView`, you have to invoke `textView.setText(...)` on the main thread.
`setText` will post a message to the main `Looper` to re-layout and invalidate the TextView (and parents). At some point in the near future, those messages will be processed and the view hierarchy will be updated.

`setText` doesn't do this work directly because this work load is heavy, and doing it directly would not allow the framework to batch up such requests.

If you then invoke `Thread.sleep(...)`, you're putting the main ui thread into a paused state, however, it is this thread which would normally perform the re-layout and invalidation of the TextView and parents.

Android wants to be able to render a new frame (if anything has changed) in under 16ms to keep a greater than 60fps. If your main thread is doing something intensive, or is paused (by sleeping) for any significant time that would threaten the 16ms, the error message you're seeing is posted to logcat.

Whilst in Lollipop the actual rendering is performed on its own render thread, it still needs timely updates from the main thread.

As for how to fix this, see Jason's answer, or alternatively, post a delayed runnable to the view itself (rather than a handler instance directly) using

```
textView.setText("show me!");    
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
         textView.setText(""); 
     }
}, 30);
```

If this is occurring regularly, avoid the allocation of the `Runnable` each time by keeping it as a field.

Note that in either case, creating an anonymous inner class (the `Runnable`) has the potential to memory leak the Activity, but that is a different story.

Comment: Ah, okay! That's good to know, thank you! The amount of time I was trying to sleep it was considerably less than 16ms, but this could very well still be the problem.